# MySQL Reducing Storage Space

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `k_timestamps` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `k_timestamp` datetime NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `data1` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  KEY `k_timestamp_key` (`k_timestamp`,`id`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `k_time_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `data` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Basically, I have a whole lot of `id` and `data1` key-value pairs, and every few hours I either add new key-value pairs not seen before to the list, or the value of a previous id has changed.  I want to track what all the values were for every `id` in time.  Thus, the `id` column can contain duplicate `id`'s and is not the primary key.

Side note, `k_time_fk` points to another, much smaller table that has common information for a particular `id` regardless of what the current time is or value it currently holds.

`(id, k_timestamp)` should be thought of as the (composite) primary key of the table.

For example,

```
id          k_timestamp            data1
1597071247  2012-11-15 12:25:47     4
1597355222  2012-11-15 12:25:47     4
1597201376  2012-11-15 12:25:47     4
1597071243  2012-11-15 13:25:47     4
1597071247  2012-11-15 13:25:47     3
1597071249  2012-11-15 13:25:47     3
```

Anyways, I ran this query:

```
SELECT concat(table_schema,'.',table_name), 
concat(round(table_rows/1000000,2),'M') rows, 
concat(round(data_length/(1024*1024*1024),2),'G') DATA, 
concat(round(index_length/(1024*1024*1024),2),'G') idx, 
concat(round((data_length+index_length)/(1024*1024*1024),2),'G') total_size, 
round(index_length/data_length,2) idxfrac 
FROM information_schema.TABLES ORDER BY data_length+index_length DESC LIMIT 20;
```

To pull space info on my table:

```
rows      Data     idx       total_size  idxfrac
11.25M    0.50G    0.87G     1.36G       1.76
```

I'm not really sure I understand this, how can the index be taking up so much space?  Is there something obvious I did wrong here, or is this normal?  I'm looking to try to reduce to footprint of this table if possible.  I'm not even really sure what that `k_timestamp_key` really buys for me, can it be safely deleted?

Comment: The k_timestamp_key is important since you are querying by time.

Comment: Is disk space really your concern? 2GB of disk space is "too cheap to measure" in most cases...

Comment: @NevilleK Looking to see if there's something obvious I can do, as my current web host only allows 2GB max for a DB size.

Answer (score 1):

The index is bigger because InnoDB tables will assign a 6 byte primary key when you have no unique column that it can treat as a unique index. All other indexes in the table also contain the primary key... see [14.2.3.12.2. Clustered and Secondary Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-table-and-index.html) from the manual

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, yes, this is pretty normal behaviour, as innvo writes.

Secondly, you can optimize the table and its index using [OPTIMIZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimize-table.html). As your primary key is likely to be "fragmented" - i.e. it's not safe to assume that an inserted row is physically next to the previous row - there may be some gains there.

Finally, you may not *need* a primary key on the table, but you almost certainly need an index if you're querying across millions of rows...